# How to extract the original entity class hidden behind a HibernateProxy?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've created a Mapper class for my application, which provides a simple interface to use:

```
Destination destination = mapper.map(sourceObject, Destination.class);

//or just

mapper.map(sourceObject, destination);
```

The Mapper instance contains the map of converters which mapped by a ClassPair:

```
class ClassPair() {

    private Class sourceType;
    private Class destinationType;
    ...
}

class Mapper {

    private Map<ClassPair, Converter> converters;
    ...
}
```

The problem is that when I'm trying to convert a persisted entity to another type, my Mapper fails with NPE. It caused by the fact that the type of the persisted entity isn't the original class of this entity, but the generated HibernateProxy implementation.

I've tried to use `Hibernate.unproxy()` method, but it took a place across all the application. It works, but, I think, it's a really bad practice.

So, I need to somehow determine the original class of an entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `HibernateProxy` instance gives access to its underlying lazy initialization handler, which has needed information.

```
if (value instanceof HibernateProxy) {
    return ((HibernateProxy) value).getHibernateLazyInitializer().getPersistentClass();
}
```